# How to convert from base 2 to base n?

Tags: number-bases

I'm trying to use baseform to convert numbers in base 10 to base n, how can I make the convertion between, say base 2 to base n?

Baseform seems to always think that the base in expr `BaseForm[Expr, n]` is always 10.

Comment: Maybe using `FromDigits` ?

Comment: Thanks, it's also a viable alternative.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It should be possible to use notation of the form `base^^number` inside the `BaseForm` expression like this:

```
BaseForm[2^^10101,14]
```

There are some similar examples under **Properties and Relations** in the [documentation for `BaseForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseForm.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy. I've read about it yesterday but it was kinda unclear to me.

Comment: Whilst looking inside a discarded Stanford Bunny, I discovered a note saying that `BaseForm` only works if `n` is less than 37.

Comment: @image_doctor I_swear_ I once was calling Stephen W. names b/c of that

Comment: @image_doctor of course as that takes you to the limit of English language keyboards. Besides, base 36 allows you to write all the rude messages you wish, unlike base 16. What is DEADBEEF, anyway?

Comment: @rcollyer :) and I thought the answer was FORTYTWO.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the above elements wrapped up in function which pulls together the various, or user defined, output forms and lets you switch from any base to any base:

```
Clear[BaseTranslator];
Options[BaseTranslator] = {BTForm -> BaseForm};
BaseTranslator[number_, base1_, base2_, 
  OptionsPattern[]] := (OptionValue@BTForm)[
  FromDigits[ToString[number], base1], base2]
```

And some sample usage:

```
BaseTranslator[100,10,4]
```

> 1210<sub>4</sub>

```
BaseTranslator[100, 10, 4 ,BTForm -> IntegerDigits]
```

> {1, 2, 1, 0}

```
BaseTranslator[100, 2, 4, BTForm -> IntegerDigits]
```

> { 1, 0}

```
BaseTranslator[102, 10, 101, BTForm -> IntegerDigits]
```

> {1, 1}

Comment: Not much love for this answer .. where does it go wrong ? :)

Comment: Votes are [elusive phantoms](http://www.hypothesisjournal.com/?p=741)

Comment: @belisarius :), I've had some success using a Laplacian of Gaussian to improve the definition of the phantom phantom and it is becoming increasingly obvious that the element that was missing from this answer is resolving towards the Stanford Bunny.

Answer (score 10):

Since numbers given in `base^^` form automatically parse as regular number, it can be at times useful to pass numbers around as strings.  For example:

```
FromDigits["100010011110011", 2]
```

> ```
> 17651
> ```

Different ways to represent that number:

```
IntegerDigits[17651, 16]

BaseForm[17651, 2]

IntegerString[17651, 2]
```

> {4, 4, 15, 3}
>
> 100010011110011<sub>2</sub>
>
> "100010011110011"

Answer (score 2):

A simplest form for BaseTranslator (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/776/image-doctor):

```
(*convert stringnumber from base1 to base2*)
convert[stringnumber_, base1_, base2_] :=    
  BaseForm[FromDigits[stringnumber, base1], base2]

convert["19a", 16, 10](*example 1*)

convert["A", 16, 2] (*example *)
```

> ```
>  410
>
>  Subscript[1010, 2]
> ```

Comment: ROSU, I formatted your code for you.  Please see [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to learn how to do this yourself.  Also, I note that this answer has been down-voted; that is likely because it removes rather than adds functionality to image_doctor's method.