# Reading numbers

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to convert base 10 number say a in base 2 say b and want that, from now b must be read as a base 10 number.
In general, I need to convert base 10 number say a in base n say b and want that, from now b must be read as a base 10 number.
how to do this? whats the commands or programme for this?

Comment: BaseForm and IntegerDigits should be helpful here.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88288/how-to-do-binary-calculation/88290#88290

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question

```
a = RandomInteger[10^5]

(* 60550 *)

BaseForm[a, 2]
```

[image]

```
b = FromDigits[IntegerDigits[a, 2]]

(* 1110110010000110 *)
```