# Printing binary numbers with extra zeros

Tags: display, binary

I have the numbers $0-64$ in binary and want them all to be displayed with 8 figures.

Expected output:

$5_{10} = 101_2$ should become `00000101`.

Comment: `IntegerString[5, 2, 8]`

Comment: is the expected output a String? or more like `BaseForm` which affects printing but not evaluation?

Comment: Related: [(6635)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6635/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unclear in your question if you are asking for a [`String`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/String.html) for [`NumberForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html).

### FORM

If you want to change the *Form* but not create a string then

```
NumberForm[BaseForm[Range[0, 64], 2], 8, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

you could define a function

```
bin8[n_Integer] := NumberForm[
  BaseForm[n, 2]
  , 8
  , NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}
  ]

bin8 /@ Range[0, 64]
```

And get the same output

### STRING

As pointed out by @swish

```
IntegerString[Range[0, 64], 2, 8]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
Row /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 8][[;; 65]]
```

> {00000000,00000001,00000010,00000011,00000100,00000101,00000110,00000111,00001000,00001001,00001010,00001011,00001100,00001101,00001110,00001111,00010000,00010001,00010010,00010011,00010100,00010101,00010110,00010111,00011000,00011001,00011010,00011011,00011100,00011101,00011110,00011111,00100000,00100001,00100010,00100011,00100100,00100101,00100110,00100111,00101000,00101001,00101010,00101011,00101100,00101101,00101110,00101111,00110000,00110001,00110010,00110011,00110100,00110101,00110110,00110111,00111000,00111001,00111010,00111011,00111100,00111101,00111110,00111111,01000000}