# How do I get 3 digits binary after calling BaseForm or IntegerDigits

Tags: conversion, binary

Let's say I have a list called 'solution', I'm converting these numbers into binary form

```
solution = {0, 6, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2}
solutionbinary = IntegerDigits[solution, 2]
```

Output like:

> {{0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0}}

My expectation:

> {{0,0,0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0,0,1}, {0,1, 1}, {1, 0,
> 1}, {0,1, 0}}

All of them must be 3 digits binary form.

Comment: `solutionbinary = IntegerDigits[solution, 2, 3]`

Comment: Yeah, It was asked https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146876/printing-binary-numbers-with-extra-zerosbut it was hard to find the title of the question. I found it after posting the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the answer is in the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146876/printing-binary-numbers-with-extra-zeros)

**Answer:**

```
  solutionbinary = IntegerDigits[solution, 2, 3]
```